# Is it okay to have multiple aims?

Tags: thought-experiment

From childhood we were told to have only one aim.  All the stories we were told were around this concept (for example, Arjuna and Fish Eye from the *Mahabharata*). If we vacillate between different career options people would advise us to concentrate on only one aim.

But many times is it not possible to have multiple interests or career choices or may be we are not yet able to find our objective? In such cases is it not an good idea to work on all interests or career options or passions?

Can anyone advise on how to decide which field is best (most interesting) for you?

Answer (score 2):

Surely it is about focus, not merely having one aim. The physicist [Chandrasekhar](http://wavefunction.fieldofscience.com/2016/10/subrahmanyan-chandrasekhar-study-in.html?m=1) is a great example of this, who switched area of study about every decade, but with great focys, and so was able to contribute greatly. If he had only had single predetermined aims, how coukd he have discovered new things, been open to where his subjects took him?

Find what you are truly passionate about, what really absorbs you. That is what you will be able to do best.